# Use the user.module API to create user in Drupal 7

Tags: php, api, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to use [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/7) in Drupal 7 to add new accounts to the system.
The function is defined as `user_save($account, $edit = array(), $category = 'account')`.

According to the documentation, the variable `$account` is a user object. How do I put together a user object that the function can process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a comment that may help you out a little regarding the user object: [User Object](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/user/7#comment-13744).  Another way to see what the user object holds is to do:

```
<?php
  global $user;
  print_r($user);
?>
```

Here is a very basic example of creating a new user with [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/7):

```
<?php    
  $edit = array(
    'name' => 'New User',
    'pass' => 'password',
    'mail' => 'myemail@example.com',
    'status' => 1,
    'language' => 'en',
    'init' => 'myemail@example.com',
    'roles' => array(2 => 'authenticated user'),
  );

  user_save(NULL, $edit);
?>
```

Comment: Passing an object for `$account` is not necessary. If you pass `NULL` as first argument, the function will replace it with a `stdClass` object, and accordingly set `$account->is_new`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Ah ok, thanks! Learned something new, edited answer:)